# Right Sidebar appears below content - Drupal Zen Subtheme

Tags: css, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am trying to create a new theme for my Drupal site. I am working with Drupal 6.20 and Zen's latest version.

I have made quite a few changes to the layout of the theme and now my right sidebar appears below the main content.

You can see the problem here (not dynamically generated - saved from a local copy) : http://testcheckchecktest.whackk.com/grab/test1.html

Most of the layout CSS can be found here : http://testcheckchecktest.whackk.com/grab/test1_files/layout-fixed.css

CSS that ***might*** be the problem :

```
.sidebar-second #content {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 0; /* LTR */
  margin-right: -800px; /* LTR */ /* Negative value of #content's width + left margin. */
}

.region-sidebar-second {
  float: left; /* LTR */
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: 800px; /* LTR */ /* Width of content + sidebar-first. */
  margin-right: -980px; /* LTR */ /* Negative value of .region-sidebar-second's width + left margin. */
  padding: 0; /* DO NOT CHANGE. Add padding or margin to .region-sidebar-second .section. */
}

.region-sidebar-second .section {
  margin: 0 0 0 0px; /* LTR */
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please, let me know if you can figure out what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends where the sidebar is placed within the HTML code. I would recommend floating both the sidebar as well as the content, this could help.

Best of luck!

Comment: both of them are floated left

Comment: #main isn't floated left.  Floating it left, caused the sidebar to jump into place.